# Code working in one account but not when copied to another

Tags: vba, outlook

I made a sub that reads some mails when Outlook is closed.

This function was created in a specific Module.

I created the Quit event in ThisOutlookSession.

It looks like this:

```
Public Sub Application_Quit()
    ReadMails
End Sub
```

The ReadMails is the sub which handles the Reading of the mails. So when a user exits Outlook this sub gets executed (and they get a message of it).

This worked at the initial user account where I implemented it.

I copied the OTM Project to another user (first I changed the old OTM of that user to .prv.otm and then pasted it in there).

When testing the ThisOutlookSession code never gets executed at the second user account. It doesn't launch the quit event on quitting Outlook.

When debugging there are no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed!

I tried to generate a new OTM file at the second user but I kept getting the error that outlook was still open/OTM was still in use. So I opened up Task Manager and ended Outlook. Suddenly, the quit event seems to work..